# Combining queries in a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to combine privileges from the user and their roles in a stored procedure. To do so currently I am running many queries. The first gets the roles the user has. Then a query to get the privileges for each role. Then a query to get the privileges for the user. Then I combine them all from the code. I would like to be able to do all that from a stored procedure. I have not ever worked with stored procedures so I do not know if it is even possible.

[image: The database structure]

Hopefully the diagram will help you understand what I am trying to do.

I started to write one but it is not near finished or functional.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_privileges
    @userId INT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        role_id 
    FROM 
        user_role 
    INNER JOIN 
        role ON user_role.role_id = role.id 
    WHERE 
        user_id = @userId;

    -- For each role
    SELECT 
        privilege_id as id, name 
    FROM 
        role_privilege 
    INNER JOIN 
        privilege ON role_privilege.privilege_id = privilege.id 
    WHERE 
        role_id = ${roleId}

    SELECT 
        privilege_id as id, name 
    FROM 
        user_privilege 
    INNER JOIN 
        privilege ON user_privilege.privilege_id = privilege.id 
    WHERE 
        user_id = @userId;
```

What do I need to do to finish the procedure?

1. Looping through the results of the first select. No clue how to do this.
2. Combining the results. Found that this could be done by making a temp table and then pushing the result sets from each query to it. Is there a better way?

---

**Sample**:

user table

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | caleb    |
+----+----------+
```

role table

```
+------+----------+
| role |   name   |
+------+----------+
|    1 | admin    |
|    2 | standard |
+------+----------+
```

privilege table

```
+-----------+---------------+
| privilege |     name      |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 | CREATE_USER   |
|         2 | DELETE_USER   |
|         3 | ADMIN_VIEW    |
|         4 | STANDARD_VIEW |
|         5 | NOTHING       |
+-----------+---------------+
```

user_privilege table

```
+---------+--------------+
| user_id | privilege_id |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 |            1 |
+---------+--------------+
```

user_role table

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | role_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

role_privilege table

```
+---------+--------------+
| role_id | privilege_id |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 |            2 |
|       1 |            3 |
|       2 |            4 |
+---------+--------------+
```

Expected result for `user_id = 1`

```
+--------------+-------------+
| privilege_id |    name     |
+--------------+-------------+
|            1 | CREATE_USER |
|            2 | DELETE_USER |
|            3 | ADMIN_VIEW  |
+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: You should be able to do this entire thing in a single query. Using loops and such is a not a great way to retrieve data.

Comment: @SeanLange Could you explain how I could do that. I just can't see how that would be don.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sidenote:

[image]

see? no line crossings, +100 for readability.

One of possible solutions (almost a translation from natural language to SQL):
*Return list of priviledges which exist in user priviledges list or any of user role priviledges list*:

```
select *
from privilege p
where exists(
  select 1 from user_privilege up
  where up.user_id = @user_id
    and up.privilege_id = p.id
)
or exists(
  select 1 from user_role ur
  inner join role_privilege rp
  on rp.role_id = ur.role_id
  where ur.user_id = @user_id
    and rp.privilege_id = p.id
)
```

not optimized but can be a good start for understanding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE get_user_privileges
  @userId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT p.[id] AS [privilege_id], p.[name]
    FROM [user] AS u
    JOIN [user_role] AS ur ON ur.[user_id] = u.[id]
    JOIN [role] AS r ON r.[id] = ur.[role_id]
    JOIN [role_privilege] AS rp ON rp.[role_id] = r.[id]
    JOIN [user_privilege]  AS up ON up.[user_id] = u.[id]
    JOIN [privilege] AS p ON p.[id] = up.[privilege_id]
    WHERE u.[id] = @userId 
    GROUP BY p.[id], p.[name] ;
END ;
```

Then you can execute this stored procedure as follows:

```sql
EXEC get_user_privileges @userId = 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is close to what I am wanting. It returns what role a user has and all of their user privileges, but it does not return any of the privileges that the roles have which is the main difficulty I have been having. All I want from this whole query is a list of privileges. I don't care at all if it cam from user or a certain role.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a stored procedure that returns all the role-privilege associations.